# Error while compiling suricata on amazon linux

Tags: linux, security, amazon-ec2, network-security, suricata

I am trying to install suricata in Amazon Linux ec2 instance
I got the following error while compiling

> ---
>
> error: process didn't exit successfully: `rustc -vV` (exit code: 1)
> --- stdout
> rustc 1.35.0
> binary: rustc
> commit-hash: unknown
> commit-date: unknown
> host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> release: 1.35.0
>
> --- stderr
> error: couldn't load codegen backend "/usr/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/codegen-backends/librustc_codegen_llvm-llvm.so": "/usr/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/codegen-backends/librustc_codegen_llvm-llvm.so: symbol _ZNK4llvm10ModulePass17createPrinterPassERNS_11raw_ostreamERKSs, version LLVM_7 not defined in file libLLVM-7.so with link time reference"
>
> ---

- Does anyone have an idea how it can be solved?
- Is there a specific rust type for Amazon Linux?

I tried to install rust manually, but it says that it already exists.
I tried to uninstall and install it again several times

[image: error image]

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue with Suricata. I am also using Amazon Linux and after some digging, the error is related to the clang library. I had to yum install this package and reconfigure and make

```
yum install llvm7.0
//reconfigure and recompile surticata
./configure --enable-rust
make
```